# XPath Custom Sort Expression

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt, xpath

I'm sorting an XSL list using Xpath.

I want to sort it chronologically, which is easy-- but some list items have duplicate titles and I want those grouped together, even if they are newer. For instance:

List item A (created 4/19)

List item B (created 4/18)

Duplicate List item B (created 4/21)

List item C (created 4/17)

--the key here is ensuring that the "Duplicate List Item B" appears beneath the original, even though it's the newest.

Right now, my expression consists only of "@Created" which is displaying the items in descending order. I need an expression that says "Sort by creation date unless a title contains the word 'duplicate' - in which case, sort those alphabetically"

Can anyone propose a custom Xpath expression that achieves this?

Thanks.

EDIT: Here is the window where' I'd enter the Xpath expression. Again, the only 2 rows I need to worry about are @Title and @Created_x0020_Date

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1koAH.png)

Comment: First group and sort the groups, then sort the items in each group. Do you use XSLT 2.0?

Comment: Please show actual XML content to help see how values are placed (text, attribute, parent, child, etc.)

Comment: @Parfait I don't have the raw XML. This is part of a sharepoint webpart which just builds out the XSL for you.

Still - it shouldn't really be necessary for this. What it comes down to is the list items have rows for the creation date and the subject. I only need an Xpath expression that says "Sort by date - unless a subject contains 'Duplicate', in which case sort those alphabetically."

Comment: @RobOt You cannot write XSLT if you don't know what the source XML looks like. If you don't see it, use the *identity transform* template to get it - then show it to us, along with the *exact* expected result (as code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without any code to go on I'm going to make a lot of assumptions. Given the following XML block:

```
<data>
  <block created="20160419" label="A"/>
  <block created="20160418" label="B"/>
  <block created="20160421" label="B"/>
  <block created="20160417" label="C"/>
</data>
```

You will need to use keys to get this to work. I am assuming XSLT 1.0 as this way it will be compatible with whichever you are using.

```
<xsl:key name="labels" match="/data/block" use="@label" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html lang="en">
        <head></head>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="/data/block[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('labels', @label))]">
                <xsl:sort select="@created" data-type="number"/>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('labels', @label )">
                    <xsl:sort select="@created" data-type="number"/>

                    <p><xsl:value-of select="@label"/> - <xsl:value-of select="@created"/></p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

Basically what we're doing here is creating a key to loop over each block based on a distinct @label value, sorted by the @created value. From there, loop again over each block using the current @label as a variable and sort once more by created date.

This gives me the following output:

```
<p>C - 20160417</p>
<p>B - 20160418</p>
<p>B - 20160421</p>
<p>A - 20160419</p>
```

Obviously this is very rough, and doesn't use templates like it should, but hopefully it explains the concepts well enough for you to be able to understand what is going on and translate it to your own code!

Comment: +1. As you have the key set up, the `<xsl:for-each select="../block[@label = $label]">` should simply be `<xsl:for-each select="key('labels', @label )">` to follow the text book approach of accessing the current group with Muenchian grouping.

Comment: Thanks @martin-honnen, I knew there had to be an easier way to do that! I will update my reply with your code.